# Change product price on payment screen

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change a product's price on the payment gateway screen.

I have tried the `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` method, this does not work.

I add the product and then try to update the price :

```
add_action('wp_loaded', array($this,'add_to_cart'), 10);

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', array( $this,  'add_custom_price'),22,2);

public function add_custom_price( $cart) {
        if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

        // Avoiding hook repetition (when using price calculations for example)
if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
    return;

// Loop through cart items
foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
    $item['data']->set_price( 40 );
}
}
```

Testing in the above function shows the price is updated though in the checkout the price remains the same.

Comment: That's the correct hook. Post the code you tried, not that you tried a specific hook.

Comment: @disinfor the code's the one logic uses in the main answer, I presume it has something todo with the payment gateway page.

Comment: @more code added

Comment: Note: as there is only **one** available argument *(not 2)* for woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook, you should set  it `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', array( $this,  'add_custom_price'), 22, 1 );` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change the last `if` statement. You might need to use `$key => $value` here:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', array( $this,  'add_custom_price'),22, 1);

public function add_custom_price( $cart) {
        if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

        // Avoiding hook repetition (when using price calculations for example)
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $key => $item ) {
        $item['data']->set_price( 40 );
    }
}
```

Also, it looks like this is in a Class. Try moving this out of your Class into your functions.php file and update the action hook:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 22, 1);`

If it works in your functions.php file, then you need to look at how your Class is getting instantiated - especially if it's getting called to late.

Edit:
LoicTheAztec caught the wrong argument count, so answer updated to reflect that.